# Why does the query work in pgadmin and cli but not in node?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgis, node-postgres

```
SELECT ST_Distance(USER_POLY,  NEW_LOC) as dist 
FROM (
  SELECT (select ST_transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint( 11.61594943945313, 48.12707189053979),4326),3857)) AS  RES_LOC,   
         (SELECT ST_Transform((select u.poly 
                               FROM USERS u 
                               WHERE u.user_id =  '83b71cee-e9b8-46cb-9bee-6d7ee6f44cc6'), 3857)) AS  USER_POLY
) AS foo
```

I have tried the query in the cli and it worked once I removed the *as dist* but using node I get the error: syntax error at or near "SELECT", I tried casting but to no avail.

Comment: Why do you use "select ST_transform" instead of just "ST_transform" ? And I think you could rewrite the query in such a way that you don't the subquery at all. Maybe this is something node can't handle

Comment: @FrankHeikens Nodejs doesn't do any syntax checks

Comment: This query can be written without any sub-queries at all: https://pastebin.com/fYgrA30i

Comment: Please post the nodejs code you were running that led to the error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are a life saver and make me much more enthusiastic about horses! TY.

Comment: On a side note, don't compute distances using `3857` as this CRS highly distort them. You can use [`ST_DistanceSphere`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html) on the geometries in `4326`

Comment: Are `NEW_LOC` and `RES_LOC` supposed to be the same?